# Spring submit has double parameter

Tags: javascript, forms, spring, form-parameter

I am new to spring web applications. When I submit a form, the request mapping is getting a "dual" parameter. 
My form is set as:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">
......
</form>
```

I use a javascript to submit the form, for example, when I submit the form for going to various pages, my javascript is like this:

```
function gotoPage(pageNumber)
{
 document.forms['myform'].action="trx?page=" + pageNumber;
 document.forms['myform'].submit();
}
```

So when I have a link like this on my jsp page,

```
<a href="javascript:gotoPage('3')">Page number: 3</a>
```

On my controller for the request mapping for /trx, I should be getting parameter page as value "3", but I am getting value as "3,3".

Any ideas why? I noticed only on the page parameter, If I use parameters like action=search or action=sort. It all works out fine.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a hidden `<input>` in the form with the name "page"?

Comment: Please show your entire form.

Comment: Well, this was stupid of me. I did check for hidden inputs and verified there was nothing like that and so I posted this question. But I just realized, I do have a parameter on my page as <select name="page">. Fixed it now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb question.  :)

Had a `<select name="page">` in the form.